# FullCalendar count total quantity of daily clientEvents

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to count the total quantity WITHIN daily events in FullCalendar to stop further events been booked on any specific day once the LIMIT reaches `4`.

Here is what i have which works okay on the daily events when it reaches `4` BUT exceeds the `qty`.

```
var eventCounter = 0;

$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
    if(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') == event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')) {
        eventCounter++;
    }
});

if(eventCounter < 4) {
    $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
    $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
} else {
    swal({
      title: "Maximum Bookings",
      text: "Sorry, the maximum number of bookings are taken for this day. Please select another date.",
      type: "warning"
    });
}
```

What i want is the `qty` count of the `event[]` per day and not the events.

Example of events array;

```
events: [
    {
        id: '233',
        title: 'Tandem Jump',
        qty: '4',
        start: '2016-11-29 00:00:00',
        end: '2016-11-29 00:00:00'
    },
    {
        id: '239',
        title: 'Tandem Jump',
        qty: '2',
        start: '2016-11-30 00:00:00',
        end: '2016-11-30 00:00:00'
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's what you need, but this will count the number of events within the given day after the day click (in month view):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    weekends: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    allDaySlot: false,
    header: {
      left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    events: [{
      title: 'event 1',
      start: '2016-12-05T16:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-05T18:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event 2',
      start: '2016-12-05T18:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-05T20:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event 3',
      start: '2016-12-07T16:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T18:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event 7',
      start: '2016-12-07T12:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T14:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event 4',
      start: '2016-12-07T11:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-07T12:00:00'
    }, {
      title: 'event 5',
      start: '2016-12-08T16:00:00',
      end: '2016-12-08T18:00:00'
    }],
    height: 'auto',
    editable: true,
    dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
      if (!allDay) {
        // strip time information
        date = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDay());
      }
      var ar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
        if (event.start.year() == date.year() && event.start.month() == date.month() && event.start.day() == date.day()) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
      console.log(ar.length);
    }
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jzajf4e8/